# Copy from one surface to another surface

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediacodec, android-graphics

I currently have two different surfaces (one from SurfaceView and another surface created from MediaCodec).

What are the different ways available to copy from one surface to another?

Comment: Can you tell more about your use case? Are you trying to display and encode video at the same time?

Comment: I'm planning to copy the data from another surface and pass it to persistent input surface of MediaCodec

Comment: A Surface is a consumer of media buffers, but who is the producer in your case?

Comment: Source => Surface View ,                                      
Destination => Surface created from MediaCodec.CreatePersistentInputSurface();

Comment: Something is missing in the flow. SurfaceView doesn't produce frames, it provides a Surface for someone else to draw onto.

Comment: Yes, Consider someone is drawing to a SurfaceView and I need to copy the contents of it to another surface. Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

In the Android graphics architecture a `Surface` plays the role of a consumer of buffers containing the graphical data (e.g. video frames).

A typical consumer does not provide access to the buffers that it holds. An exception is the special type `ImageReader` that allows direct application access to image data rendered into its `Surface`.

There is a less efficient way to copy the contents of a `SurfaceView` into a `Bitmap` using `PixelCopy`. While `TextureView` allows you to get the `Bitmap` directly.

You can then draw the `Bitmap` image onto another `Surface` using its `Canvas`.

Links:

https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-sh

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface#lockCanvas(android.graphics.Rect)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: If I have a surface, is it possible to attach to a SurfaceView or any drawing handler?

Comment: Behind the scenes a Surface works with a queue of buffers. It has to release buffers back to the queue after consuming them. If a Surface would be connected to two different objects, how would it know that both objects are done handling the current buffer?

Comment: Ok, can you please share some inputs on possibilities to draw on to the second surface if I have some content drawn on to a different surfaceview? I understand what you are saying but I didn't find a way to "copy/transfer" the contents drawn in one surfaceview to  a surface (as i have surface alone but not any handler attached to it).

Comment: A Surface is like an interface that allows you to draw on it, but not to read from it. If your Surface was created from a SurfaceView for example, then you can copy the Bitmap from the source SurfaceView using PixelCopy. Then you lock the canvas of the destination Surface and draw the Bitmap on it.

Comment: Ok, we are getting closer, which is a great sign. Any other ways to copy other than with bitmap as I see it could be a costly operation to do it every frame and draw.

Comment: I saw here (https://github.com/SkyDragonGPlay/GPlayUnity/blob/e10b95187e4e0a7caf14de97f43b8dec08b79966/framework/UnityRuntime/src/main/java/com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer.java#L248) that they are able to create a surfaceview from surface. So wondering if its possible to do the same.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the above example they create a regular SurfaceView, take its Surface and draw on it with OpenGL.

Comment: Can you please share any pointers on drawing to surface with OpenGL?

Comment: Docs are pretty useful: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl

Comment: This project has a lot if example code: https://github.com/google/grafika

Comment: @dev.bmax Assuming I had an `ImageReader`, how would I be able to write those `Image`s to another Surface (e.g. one from MediaRecorder)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76914334/